# Bootstrap tabs are not working via AJAX in a modal

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-tabs

**It working fine without modal and ajax.** But when I load tabbed panel in modal using ajax it does not select `Tab Panes`.

```
<!-- Nav tabs -->
<ul class="nav nav-tabs tabs-left">
    <li class="active tab-selection"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#financial">Financial</a></li>
    <li class="tab-selection"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#marketing">Marketing</a></li>
</ul>

<!-- Tab panes -->
<div class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane active" id="financial">Financial Tab</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="marketing">Marketing Tab</div>      
</div>
```

AJAX

```
$.ajax({
        url : url,
        type : "POST", 
        success:function(data){
            $(".modal-body").html(data);
        }
  });
```

My Modal

```
<div aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" role="dialog" tabindex="-1" id="previewForm" class="modal fade">
  <div class="modal-dialog" style="width: 675px">
    <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button data-dismiss="modal" class="close" type="button"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
        <h3 id="myModalLabel" class="modal-title">Preview</h3>
    </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
        </div>  
    </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You're trying to add some HTML to an element with class `.modal-body`, but there is no element with that class in your HTML code.

Comment: Code structure is fine and modal is also there in my code. Without modal it working fine also.

Comment: I can't see `modal` anywhere in the code you've posted, could you post some more?

Comment: I can suggest loading tab content by tab click

Comment: @ncocacola I updated question with my modal code

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found alternative solution to show `tabbed-panel` of associated `nav-tab` like following.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on("click",".modal-body li a",function()
    {
        tab = $(this).attr("href");
        $(".modal-body .tab-content div").each(function(){
            $(this).removeClass("active");
        });
        $(".modal-body .tab-content "+tab).addClass("active");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

**Tab with data-attribute is execute on document load**. 
You're calling it **by ajax**, so just **init the tab component on success**.

*Here is an exemple (not with ajax, but with button click) :*

**Bootply** : http://www.bootply.com/sNQH8hGFY9

**Your code** :

```
 $.ajax({
            url : url,
            type : "POST", 
            success:function(data){
                $(".modal-body").html(data);
                $('.modal-body .nav').tab();  //  <--- Look Here
            }
      });
```

Comment: Thanks for your co-operate but `Nav-tab` is work but it associated `tabbed-panel` not working

Answer (score 1):

Also make sure the "tab's" id are unique to the page.